# Change port number for SQL 2012 Cluster

Tags: sql-server-2012, clustering, failover

I have been trying to change the port number of a SQL 2012 cluster with little success.  I had thought that I could just do this the same way as normal through configuration manager however, even with the services down in the cluster and changing the port on both nodes the old port number remains.

I have started reading about the need to remove and then add in checkpoints for the cluster but have been unable to find anything relating to SQL 2012.

I am assuming I need to use the PowerShell commands for `Remove-ClusterCheckpoint` and `Add-ClusterCheckpoint` but if I am honest I am not clear what parameters I should be using.

Has anyone done this for SQL 2012 on Windows 2012 R2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cluster instances use registry keys checkpointing to ensure that all nodes in the cluster share the same configuration. Checkpointing works while the resource (the SQL Server Service in this case) is online. When the resource is offline, checkpointing doesn't happen.

In the context of your issue, just change the port from the configuration manager on the active node while the service is running.

As an alternative, you can edit the contents of the checkpoint file directly, as described in the section "Method 1" in [this page](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn169045(v=sql.110).aspx).

As far as removing/adding checkpoints with PowerShell is concerned, the syntax is straightforward:

```
Get-ClusterCheckpoint #lists all checkpoints

#remove checkpoint
Remove-ClusterCheckpoint -ResourceName "SQL Network Name (InstanceName)" -RegistryCheckpoint "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.InstanceId\MSSQLServer" 

#add checkpoint
Add-ClusterCheckpoint -ResourceName "SQL Network Name (InstanceName)" -RegistryCheckpoint "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL11.InstanceId\MSSQLServer"
```

Comment: OK so I only need to run the commands if the resources are offline.  However I was noticing that even when I changed the port on the active node with the resource up, when I restarted it reverted back to the old port.

Comment: Weird. It's working for me. Are you restarting configuration manager after cycling the instance?

Comment: I will have to wait till OOH again before I can try, we have noticed an issue with some of the cluster disks which is clouding the issue.  Although I don't see how that would affect the registry of the servers (I might be wrong).

Comment: Now I remember that I had one of my clustered instances doing this and I think I fixed it with the remove/add checkpoint. However the correct behavior is automatic checkpointing. Look in the cluster logs to see if something interesting turns up.

Answer (score 0):

There is another method to resolve it as follows:

1. Open configuration manager on Active Node -- Goto TCP/IP properties of SQL instance --> on Protocol Tab change "Listen All" to No
2. Go to Ip Addresses tab and set TCP Port (IPALL) to 1433 or yourchoice. Remove TCP Dynamic Port.
3. pause SQL instance in cluster manager
4. come back to Consgfiguration manager and restart the SQL instance/agent. Once SQL services are up, it should also come up in cluster manager
5. Connect to SQL instance and check errorlog for port change. you will be happy :)

now repeat Step 1, 2 only on another node and failover and Failback SQL instance. All good.